# convert this to java

Tags: java, actionscript-3

I'm trying to convert this ase file encoder from actionscript 3 to java:

```
const FILE_SIGNATURE : String = "ASEF";

function encode ( pixels : Array ):ByteArray
{
    var swatch : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var ase : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    var hex:String;
    var pix:uint;

    ase.writeUTFBytes (FILE_SIGNATURE);// header
    ase.writeInt (0x10000);// version
    ase.writeInt (pixels.length * 2);// blocks

    for (var i : int = 0; i < pixels.length; ++i)
    {
        pix = pixels[i];
        swatch.length = 0;

        // start of group

        ase.writeShort (0xC001);
        ase.writeInt (0);
        ase.writeShort (1);

        // swatch name

        hex = pix.toString(16);
        while (hex.length < 6) hex = "0" + hex;

        swatch.writeShort ((hex = "#" + hex).length + 1);
        for (var n : int = 0; n < hex.length; ++n) swatch.writeShort (hex.charCodeAt(n));
        swatch.writeShort (0);

        // colours

        swatch.writeUTFBytes ("RGB ");
        swatch.writeFloat ((pix >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255);
        swatch.writeFloat ((pix >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255);
        swatch.writeFloat ((pix & 0xFF) / 255);
        swatch.writeShort (2);

        // write swatch

        ase.writeInt (swatch.length);
        ase.writeBytes (swatch);
    }

    return ase;
}
```

This is what I have come up, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
public void Encoder(int[] pixels, File output) throws IOException {
        String FILE_SIGNATURE = "ASEF";
        DataOutputStream ase = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(output));
        DataOutputStream swatch = new DataOutputStream(ase);
        String hex;
        int pix;

        ase.writeUTF(FILE_SIGNATURE);
        ase.writeInt (0x10000);// version
        ase.writeInt (pixels.length * 2);// blocks

        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; ++i)
        {
            pix = pixels[i];

            // start of group
            ase.writeShort (0xC001);
            ase.writeInt (0);
            ase.writeShort (1);

            // swatch name
            hex = Integer.toHexString(pix);


            while (hex.length() < 6) hex = "0" + hex;

            swatch.writeShort ((hex = "#" + hex).length() + 1);
            for (int n = 0; n < hex.length(); ++n) swatch.writeShort (hex.charAt(n));
            swatch.writeShort (0);

            // colours
            swatch.writeUTF("RGB ");
            swatch.writeFloat ((pix >> 16 & 0xFF) / 255);
            swatch.writeFloat ((pix >> 8 & 0xFF) / 255);
            swatch.writeFloat ((pix & 0xFF) / 255);
            swatch.writeShort (2);

            // write swatch
            ase.writeInt (swatch.size());
            ase.writeBytes (swatch.toString());
        }

    }
```

I think the problem is with the last line `ase.writeBytes (swatch.toString());`, because the output contains "java.io.DataOutputStream@..." instead of the data that outputstream has.

Do I have to use a different method than DataOutputStream or I just have a mistake somewhere? Please help.

Comment: "It doesn't work", with no other information besides source, makes a poor question on this site.  Show us what you've tried, indicate what it is that confuses you, at the very least tell us what doesn't work.  This site does a really excellent job at specific technical questions, less so with requests that someone debug something for you.

Comment: @arcy I explained what the problem is in the edit.

Comment: What do you think `swatch.toString()` does and why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Well I tried to convert `ase.writeBytes (swatch)`. The idea is to write to ase the contents of swatch.

Comment: Ok, so you think `swatch.toString()` contains the contents of `swatch`? Why do you think so?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It was the only method the DataOutputstream swatch had that didn't deal with writing to it. I really don't know how to convert that line correctly.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the javadoc and looking very closely at `DataOutputStream swatch = new DataOutputStream(ase);` and how that compares to `var swatch : ByteArray = new ByteArray();`.